# django rest framework: custom permission for GET request

Tags: django-rest-framework

i have this view handling only /GET/ request to display all authors only if the logged user is superuser

```
class AuthorView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    permission_class = (IsSuperUser,)
```

And the permission for superuser:

```
class IsSuperUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        return user.is_authenticated() and user.is_superuser
```

The permission does not seems to be working, placed the `pdb` in `has_permission` the control does not seems to coming there.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
permission_classes = (IsSuperUser,)
```

and not

```
permission_class = (IsSuperUser,)
```